# Python program to invert mouse movement when left and right click are simultaneously pressed not working

Tags: python, mouse, ctypes

I am new to python and I was trying to fool around with making a program so that when you are pressing left click and right click it inverts the mouse movement. It runs but it doesnt do anything.
Can someone point me what am I doing wrong?

```
import ctypes
import time
import keyboard

# Constants for mouse button states
LEFT_MOUSE_BUTTON = 0x01
RIGHT_MOUSE_BUTTON = 0x02

# Get the screen width and height
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
SCREEN_WIDTH = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0)
SCREEN_HEIGHT = user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)

# Store the initial mouse position
initial_x, initial_y = 0, 0
user32.GetCursorPos(ctypes.byref(ctypes.wintypes.POINT(initial_x, initial_y)))

# Flag to indicate if the mouse movement is inverted
invert_movement = False

# Flag to indicate if 'X' key has been pressed
x_key_pressed = False

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('X') and not x_key_pressed:
        x_key_pressed = True
        invert_movement = not invert_movement
        if invert_movement:
            print("Enabled")  # Print enabled when the program is turned on
        else:
            print("Disabled")  # Print disabled when the program is turned off
        time.sleep(0.2)  
    
    # Check if the 'X' key is released to reset the toggle flag
    if not keyboard.is_pressed('X'):
        x_key_pressed = False
    
    # Check the state of the left and right mouse buttons
    left_button_pressed = user32.GetKeyState(LEFT_MOUSE_BUTTON) & 0x8000 != 0
    right_button_pressed = user32.GetKeyState(RIGHT_MOUSE_BUTTON) & 0x8000 != 0
    
    # If both left and right buttons are pressed, invert the mouse movement
    if left_button_pressed and right_button_pressed and x_key_pressed:
        invert_movement = not invert_movement
    
    # Get the current mouse position
    current_x, current_y = 0, 0
    user32.GetCursorPos(ctypes.byref(ctypes.wintypes.POINT(current_x, current_y)))
    
    # Calculate the change in mouse position
    delta_x = current_x - initial_x
    delta_y = current_y - initial_y
    
    # Invert the movement if required
    if invert_movement:
        delta_x = -delta_x
        delta_y = -delta_y
    
    # Update the mouse position if there's any change
    if delta_x != 0 or delta_y != 0:
        new_x = initial_x + delta_x
        new_y = initial_y + delta_y
        
        # Ensure the new position is within the screen bounds
        new_x = max(0, min(SCREEN_WIDTH - 1, new_x))
        new_y = max(0, min(SCREEN_HEIGHT - 1, new_y))
        
        # Move the mouse cursor
        user32.SetCursorPos(new_x, new_y)
        
        # Update the initial position for the next iteration
        initial_x, initial_y = new_x, new_y
        
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

trying to invert mouse movement while both left and right click are pressed

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the reason your program doesn't do anything is that your code to get the cursor position is not correct. I don't actually know how the POINT structure works, but it seems you need to store a reference to it and access its values after a function call, like this:

```py
pt = ctypes.wintypes.POINT()
user32.GetCursorPos(ctypes.byref(pt))
current_x, current_y = pt.x, pt.y
```